# Git Push - Not working

Tags: git

I am relative new to git and wanted to test it out. My webhosting allows GIT via SSH and I found some tutorials, but now I am stuck. Sorry in first place if my question sound stupid.

What I did:

1. Logged into my remote Webhost via SSH and initialized a new git project:

   ```
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m 'version 1.0.0'
   ```

This outputted me a very long list of files, that have been updated.

2. I cloned the repository on my local computer and created a new file "index2.php"

   ```
   git clone XXX.git
   cp index.php index2.php
   git add index2.php
   git commit -m "Index2.php added"
   ```
3. Then I tried to push the new "index2.php" file onto my server. Got an error so I had to set on the remote server `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore`

   ```
   git push origin master
   Counting objects: 2, done.
   Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 231 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
   Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
   To ssh://XXX.git
   1b79ddf..1cfe422  master -> master
   ```
4. Seems like the files have been pushed. But when I do a ls -l on my remote server the new file "index2.php" is not there. Why? Have I forgotten something?

UPDATE: 
When I do a git status on my remote server I get the following:

```
    git status
    On branch master
    Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    index2.php
```

What does this mean?

Comment: what does git log command show on your remote server? Does it show the commit "Index2.php added"?

Comment: This is the output of the log: commit 1b79ddf432ea910056c5b4be7e8a637dd4ef1124
Author: Daniel Barenkamp <db@db-dzine.de>
Date:   Wed Jul 26 09:42:53 2017 +0200

    index2 added

Comment: _"Got an error so I had to set on the remote server git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore"_ - you should have stopped there, because you are doing something you should not be doing. You should create a bare repository on the server and only push there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are able to see "index2.php added" commit when you do a `git log` on the remote server. Correct me if I am wrong. These are the things you can do.

1. Check if index2.php is present in the actual git repo pushed.
2. Do a `git pull` on the remote server to get all the latest commits pushed.

**Edit 1:**

That means there is no remote configured on the remote. You need to do `git remote add origin XXX.git` in your remote server

**Here's what has happened.**

You initialized an empty git repo on the remote server and added a commit. But you haven't pushed the changes to the git server. Essentially your remote server is not connected to any git server. If you observe, doing `git log` on your local will not show the commit you did on the remote server.

Comment: Git log says the index2 has been added.  Also it is present in my local repository. Git Pull gives me the following error `fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.`

Comment: But the remote server is my "git server" (there is git installed). I do not have any other git server. Or may I misunderstand something?

Comment: So help me understand something. git will be at two places. One on local and one on the server hosting the git. git server can be popular vendors like github, bitbucket, gitlab etc. I assume your remote and local are two systems which are trying to pull and push from the actual git server. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Then you are wrong. I have one remote server, where git is installed. This is where I want to push my things from my local PC. No Github, Bitbucket etc. involved.

Comment: okay. I think the other answer is closer to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Git is usually used with bare clones on remote. That is how GitHub/BitBucket and other providers work like. So, you need to create a bare repository in your SSH server to be able to push changes without need of any further configuration. To convert your existing repository to bare one, do following:

1. SSH into your server.
2. Create a new directory somewhere else (`repos` for e.g.), `cd` in.
3. Clone old repository within the server as **bare** clone.

   git clone --bare old_location
4. Clone to your local computer using the new location without changing git settings.

You can delete the old location after everything works fine.

Comment: Did that but now I have a folder "xxx-2" with only one directory in it "xxx.git" ...

Comment: That might be excessive, perhaps rename `xxx-2` to something like `repos` for having a better location overall? That would be your new path while cloning to your local computer. Added suggestion to step 2 in the answer.